# Nicer way to optionally include String in ES6 String template

Tags: string, templates, ecmascript-6

I want to display **hello username** if a condition `isLoggedIn` is true, and just **hello** otherwise.

I'm using ES6 String templates to try to make the syntax nicer than plain old string concatenation. However the best way I've found to do it is the following ([es6fiddle](http://www.es6fiddle.net/igo1lwrq/))

```
`hello ${isLoggedIn(false) ? username : ''}`
```

It's still not very nice syntax, particularly in longer templates where there is more than one variable I want to do this with.

I have been trying to find a syntax which includes strings optionally into templates, based on a condition, but I don't think there is one. Something like this would be nicer:

```
`hello ${condition && username}`
```

But, it renders **false** into the String if the condition is false.

I also tried baking the truthiness of `username` into the variable itself, i.e. have `username` be `undefined` or `null` if it doesn't exist - however the string template then just renders **undefined** or **null**.

**Can anyone recommend a nicer syntax, or approach, or is the first method the best I'm going to do with String templates?**

Comment: To get what you want, `condition` would have to be `""`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `condition && value || ""`, but that's about as horrible as the ternary operator.

I guess your best bet is to use a tagged template here that discards empty values:

```
function nonEmpty(parts) {
    var res = parts[0];
    for (var i=1; i<parts.length; i++) {
        if (arguments[i]) // you might want to handle `0` different
            res += arguments[i];
        res += parts[i];
    }
    return res;
}

console.log(nonEmpty`hello ${mockIsLoggedIn(false) && username}`);
```

Comment: nice, hadn't looked into tagged templates

Answer (score 22):

For those of you that landed here by googling something like "print variable in template literal if not null", this might help:

```
html = `<input type="text" placeholder="${data.placeholder || ''}" ... />`
```

**2023 Update:**

As Bryan mentions, a better approach today is to use the nullish coalescing operator:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="${data.placeholder ?? ''}" ... />
```

Comment: As a more modern approach, I'd recommend the nullish coalescing operator (`??`):
`<input type="text" placeholder="${data.placeholder ?? ''}" ... />`

It's the same number of characters as this answer but less error-prone since it only falls back for null and undefined... not other falsey values like 0. Maybe good to add to this answer?

Answer (score 8):

Coming back to this after a while, I think the nicer pattern as alluded to in the comment and other answer is indeed to completely separate the logic of resolving the variable from the template.

That allows you to get the desired syntax.

```
const username = isLoggedIn ? getUsername(): '';
const display = `hello${username && ' ' + username}`
```

Or, simpler, but conflating the spacing/layout of the template with the variable a bit..

```
const username = isLoggedIn ? ' ' + getUsername() : '';
const display = `hello${username}`
```

It's not a one-liner, but actually in most cases that's likely to be a good thing.